# Will an alert created on Google Cloud Platform (on section Budget & Alerts) restrict my spending if it goes over the specified amount?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

About Google Cloud Platform, section Budget & Alerts.
If I go over the configured Budget on 'Budgets & alerts' session, will the service stop working? It is not clear to me if this section is just about alerts or if it will limit the services provided by Google.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceeding your budget does not impact your running resources, or your ability to use more.

Setting a budget lets you track how your expenditure is growing relative to your budget. You can also create alerts to notify you when spending exceeds a percentage of your budget.